# padAngle property of react-vis radial pie chart not working

Tags: javascript, react-vis

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNrlt.png)

[What is being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEafX.png)

[What I was hoping for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAioQ.png)

I've tried numerous values, and I haven't been able to change anything.
Working from these docs: http://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/other-charts/radial-chart

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes it seem like *padAngle* should be set in the data objects, however it actually should be a prop of the RadialChart component:

```
<RadialChart 
  data={...}
  ...
  padAngle={0.1}
/>
```